# Confused on what to use, If Then or Case Else Statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to determine if I should use a CASE Statement or an IF THEN statement to get my results.

I want a SQL statement to run when a certain condition exists, but am not certain on how to check for the condition. Here is what I am working on

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT source FROM map WHERE rev_num =(SELECT MAX(rev_num) from MAP <-- at this point it would return either an A or B -->
```

What ever the answer is i then need to run a set of SQL's. So for A it would do this set of statements and for B it would do another.

Comment: Case is short form for if then isn't it...

Comment: `CASE` is used _within_ a SQL statement.  `IF/THEN` use used to choose _which_ query to execute.

Comment: @Steve No, they serve different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is used *within* a SQL statement.  `IF/THEN` can be used to choose *which* query to execute.

Based on your somewhat vague example it seems like you want to execute different queries based on some condition.  In that case, an `IF`/`THEN` seems more appropriate.

If, however, the majority of each query is identical and you're just changing part of the query then you *may* be able to use `CASE` to reduce the amount of duplicate code.

Comment: More precisely, `IF...ELSE` is [flow control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187471(v=sql.105).aspx).  `CASE` is an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx).